# Python: How to use SQLALCHEMY to filter SQL object in array

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy query in python where I want to filter output if a column value exists in a locally created array.
However, this always returns None.

```
offices = ['US', 'UK', 'MEX']
users_db = models.s.query(models.User).filter(models.User.location in offices).all()
```

Is there a different implementation to that in SQLAlchemy or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in_` to create SQL `IN` clause.

```py
models.s.query(models.User).filter(models.User.location.in_(offices)).all()
```